# Swift OSX dynamically add items to a scroll list

Tags: swift, scroll, nsscrollview

In an app I created, I drag and dropped a '`Scroll View`' to the main storyboard. This automatically creates a `NSScrollView`, inside of which is an `NSClipView`, inside of which is an `NSView`. Fine.

What I would like to achieve is to dynamically add checkboxes to that scroll view. I don't know how many checkboxes there will be in advance (which is why I need a scroll).

adding a subView to either the `NSScrollView` or the `NSClipView` actually displays some checkboxes, *but the scroll is not enabled*. Adding a subView to the `NSView` renders nothing.

Edit: I have also tried to modify the `NSScrollView`, `NSClipView`, and `NSView`'s height, with no luck.

How can I enable the scrolling when too many checkboxes are added to the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the trick to this is creating a container view (i.e. `NSView`) to hold the buttons.  When you create a `NSScrollView` in the storyboard, it creates `NSClipView` and `NSView` for you.  After you add or remove a button to the `NSView` (you can create your own, or use the one provided), set the `documentView` of the scroller to the view that contains your buttons.  That resets everything properly in the scroller, and you should be scrolling!  If you change the size of the view that represents the scrolling content, you just reassign that view to `scroller.documentView` and it will update everything accordingly.

Here is a horrible example of adding 20 buttons to a scroller that will scroll:

```
let documentView = NSView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,200,1200))

for index in 0..<20 {
  let offset = CGFloat(index * 50)
  let button = NSButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, offset, 150, 50 ))
  documentView.addSubview(button)
}

scrollView.documentView = documentView
```

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/Creating.html) on this gives more detail and further options you may want to set.

Hope this helps!